# Implement Owebia rules

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote

this is the first time I'm working with owebia rules so as I don't really know where to start.

I need to implement somes rules under some circumstances

Exemple :

- If I have in my cart a specific set of products : Then the delivery price of the command need to be free.

I can quickly filter and find the products I want with something like that

```
$items = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$productFreeSetDeliveryPrice = explode(";", $this->scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/cpy/product_free_delivery', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE));
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->getProductId(), $productReYt)) {
        .... TODO IMPLEMENT THE RULE TO GET FREE DELIVERY...
    }
}
```

But I don't really know where I'm supposed to add this peace of code...neither as how i'm supposed to set the delivery free.

This seems to be all related to Owebia rules...but as I'm telling you I don't know where to find them neither how it works :/
Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Owebia love array filters and array maps which is sometimes hard to wrap one's head around. Compact but cryptic.

For completeness you find the configuration in a popup in the shop -> configuration -> sales -> shipping methods.

I always have to work in an editor then copy it back in

That file needs to contain one or more

```
addMethod('unique_code', [
    'title'      => your title,  
    'enabled'    => your condition that returns true/false,
    'price'      => an expression or call to function that returns an amount
]);
```

**It can contain other php code above that defining variables OR functions** that can be called so you would define your list of IDs before. I recommend defining anything that you might need in more than one method, anything really long, or anything that will change periodically at the top. I define all my "postcode" rules and a function that calculates the number of boxes needed, so that the rules below are easier to scan and only contain the "price per box" and "cap"

Owebia's documentation gives a lot of examples of what to put in the price and enabled lines for all sorts of scenarios, but oddly not a list of skus.You can find examples there https://owebia.com/doc/en/magento2-module-advanced-shipping#ex:products

Two examples hopefully you can adapt one to make it work for you (depending if people are allowed to have other products in their cart or not)

```
addMethod('id_013', [
    'title'      => "If at least one product has the attribute 'name' equal to 'Cat'",
    'enabled'    => count(
                        array_filter($request->all_items, function ($item) {
                            return $item->product->name == 'Cat';
                        })
                    ) > 0,
    'price'      => 0
]);
addMethod('id_013', [
    'title'      => "If all items have the option 'Size' greater or equal to 1",
    'enabled'    => count(
                        array_filter($request->all_items, function ($item) {
                            return isset($item->options['Size']) && $item->options['Size']['value'] >= 1;
                        })
                    ) == $request->package_qty,
    'price'      => 10
])
```

;

Just thinking out loud but

```
    'enabled'    => count(
                        array_filter($request->all_items, function ($item) {
                            return in_array($item->product->sku, $productReYt)
                        })
                    ) > 0,
```

Your logic might need to be more clever, like calling a subroutine you have written higher up (I tend to do that as the same logic is used for different entries, just with different final prices). Other attributes of the products are also accessible so you might make this more manageable by using an attribute of the products rather than a hard coded id or sku list.

Good luck!

Comment: owebia also has a log function that you can turn on then see in the admin, very useful when you are testing